# Python and MSSQL: Filtering techniques while retrieving data from SQL

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a MS SQL Table as follows

```
Device ID       Timestamp               Avg_PF  THDV_Sum
863071010842661 2014-01-01 22:05:57     4.0       7.0   
865733020495321 2016-08-19 17:20:09     0.0       0.0  
865733020495321 2016-08-19 17:20:41     0.0       0.0   
865733020495321 2016-08-19 17:20:41     0.0       0.0
```

There are 287,533 rows comprising data for 30 devices (i.e. there are 30 unique Device ID) at 10/15 mins interval.
I want to retrieve data where TimeStamp date >=2018-10-01. In SSMS (SQL server 2014 Management Tool) I am able to do this easily using the following SQL

```
SELECT Device ID, Timestamp, Avg_PF, THDV_Sum 
FROM mytable
WHERE Timestamp >= '2018-10-01'
```

Now I am trying to the same on python using the following way

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('details of SQL server')
df_select = pd.read_sql_query(sql,conn)
```

Here I am using the above SQL statement as `sql` string. However, it is retrieving the entire data starting from `timestamp = 2014-01-01`. 
I think I need to modify the `sql` string in the `pd.read_sql_query`. 
My question is how can I add filter like stuffs in `sql` string which I can use in `pd.read_sql_query`.

Comment: What is the _actual_ value of `sql` that you pass to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about it like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
%%time -- just to measure

# Parameters
ServerName = "SQLSRV01" -- your input
Database = "Database"
Driver = "driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0"

# Create the connection
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + ServerName + '/' + Database + "?" + Driver)

df = pd.read_sql_query ("SELECT Device ID, Timestamp, Avg_PF, THDV_Sum 
                         FROM mytable
                         WHERE Timestamp >= '2018-10-01'"
                       , engine)
```

Comment: Thanks SQL_M. It worked. Actually, what I did was `sql='SELECT Device ID, Timestamp, Avg_PF, THDV_Sum FROM mytable WHERE Timestamp >= "2018-10-01" ' ` i.e. just reverse the position of single quote by double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parse_dates argument of the read_sql_query function like so:

```
df_select = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, parse_dates=['Timestamp'])
```

Comment: `parse_dates` is applied _after_ the query is executed.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Could you provide some documentation for this assumption? Anyway, I think what is important for OP is what is retrieved after the query is ran and using the parse_dates argument as mentioned would get the job done.