# Python: read data from SQL Server into dataframe with dynamic date filter

Tags: sql-server, pandas

This question can be thought as a follow up for [Python and MSSQL: Filtering techniques while retrieving data from SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016965/python-and-mssql-filtering-techniques-while-retrieving-data-from-sql)

Basically, I want to retrieve data from SQL Server for a date range set dynamically.

As of now, I am able to run the following code successfully.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=server IP address;DATABASE=dbname;UID=userid;PWD=psswd')
query_pf = "select * from PowerFactor where DeviceTimeStamp between '2019-03-07' and '2019-03-07' "
df_pf = pd.read_sql_query(query_pf,cnxn)
```

I want the two dates to be set as dynamic. Something like `today 00:00:45` and `today -1 23:59:59`

How it can be done? Perhaps I need to pass a `param` in `dict` format?

Answer (score 0):

DATEADD(hour, 2, '2017/08/25')

Use getdate() for current date if needed
Select DATEADD(hour, 2, '2017/08/25')

```
query_pf = "select * from PowerFactor where DeviceTimeStamp between 
Convert(datetime,'2006-12-30 00:38:54',120) and  Convert(datetime,'2006-12-30 00:38:54',120)
```

I think this is most flexible solution for you and you can pass the date time you want .The getdate is not goot enough as you cannot run pass old dates  function .So generate date time string in  right format Convert(datetime,'2006-12-30 00:38:54',120).

```
DATE & TIME FORMATS
0   select convert(varchar, getdate(), 0)   Dec 12 2006 12:38AM
9   select convert(varchar, getdate(), 9)   Dec 30 2006 12:38:54:840AM
13  select convert(varchar, getdate(), 13)  30 Dec 2006 00:38:54:840AM
20  select convert(varchar, getdate(), 20)  2006-12-30 00:38:54
21  select convert(varchar, getdate(), 21)  2006-12-30 00:38:54.840
22  select convert(varchar, getdate(), 22)  12/30/06 12:38:54 AM
25  select convert(varchar, getdate(), 25)  2006-12-30 00:38:54.840
100 select convert(varchar, getdate(), 100) Dec 30 2006 12:38AM
109 select convert(varchar, getdate(), 109) Dec 30 2006 12:38:54:840AM
113 select convert(varchar, getdate(), 113) 30 Dec 2006 00:38:54:840
120 select convert(varchar, getdate(), 120) 2006-12-30 00:38:54
121 select convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) 2006-12-30 00:38:54.840
126 select convert(varchar, getdate(), 126) 2006-12-30T00:38:54.840
127 select convert(varchar, getdate(), 127) 2006-12-30T00:38:54.840
```

Comment: did you mean `dateadd(day,1,getdate()) and getdate()`

Comment: you can use  select * from PowerFactor where DeviceTimeStamp between 
Convert(datetime,'2019-12-30 00:00:45',120) and  Convert(datetime,'2019-12-30 23:59:59',120)